# Unix or Windows based web service for file server

Tags: open-source, web-apps, file-management, search-engine

I am looking for web applications (preferably Tomcat deployed) similar to [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) but use it to:

- Search based on file extensions
- Search based on file names
- Search based on file content (may be via Apache's Lucene)
- Index the search space (based on a ROOT folder) for faster search
- Upload new files with a description (which is used for indexing)
- Open Source

Let me know of any softwares that are close to this requirement. I would like to deploy it in my network.

Comment: Any close by app is also okay. I dont know where to start with.

Comment: Did you try ownCloud? http://owncloud.org/ Your requirements are quite basic. :)